# The telegram bot I created using python isn't updating it's outputs when I edit the script

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I created a telegram bot using the pip python-telegram-bot. It was working smoothly after the first debugging ,but now when I try to change/add outputs or edit the code at all it doesn't affect the bot whatsoever .
I tried to rerun the script hoping it had something to do with internet latency and telegram's servers which didn't help.

```
from typing import final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes

TOKEN: final = "(Redacted)"
BOT_USERNAME: final = '@ForsakenEarth_bot'


async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('bot works')


async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('Help command works')


async def custom_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('custom command works')


def handle_response(text: str) -> str:
    processed: str = text.lower()
    if 'hello' in processed:
        return 'hey there'
    if 'how are you' in processed:
        return 'Im fine'
    if 'test' in processed:
        return "Failed"
    if 'select' in processed:
        return start()
    return 'I do not understand'


async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
    text: str = update.message.text
    print(f'User({update.message.chat.id}) in {message_type}: "{text}"')

    if message_type == 'supergroup' or message_type == 'group':
        if BOT_USERNAME in text:
            new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, '').strip()
            response: str = handle_response(new_text)
        else:
            return
    else:
        response: str = handle_response(text)

    print('Bot:', response)
    await update.message.reply_text(response)


async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update{update} caused error{context.error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting bot...')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('custom', custom_command))

    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handle_message))

    app.add_error_handler(error)

    print('polling...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

Comment: You should provide some code, as well as a reproducible example. How are we suppose to help you if we don't know anything about the script?